# Nan Error Date in Safari IPhone/IPad

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, nan

a : int exp: 1389334939
    in Chrome,FireFox,IE : 08:53 19/02/2014;
    in Safari (Iphone/Ipad) : NaN:NaN NaN/NaN/NaN;
    How to fix this?'

```
function formatDateTime(a) {
    var e = [
        [11, 'sáng'],
        [14, 'trưa'],
        [19, 'chiều']
    ];
    var f = ['chủ nhật', 'thứ hai', 'thứ ba', 'thứ tư', 'thứ năm', 'thứ sáu', 'thứ bảy'];
    var g = new Date();
    var j = new Date(a * 1000);
    var d = Math.floor(g.getTime() / 1000) - a;
    if (d < 60) return d + ' giây trước';
    if (d < 3600) return Math.floor(d / 60) + ' phút trước';
    if (d < 43200) return Math.floor(d / 3600) + ' tiếng trước';
    var h = j.getHours();
    var m = fill2(j.getMinutes());`enter code here`
    if (d < 518400) {
        var b = 'tối';
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) if (h < e[i][0]) {
            b = e[i][1];
            break
        }
        d = (g.getDay() + 7 - j.getDay()) % 7;
        var k = '';
        var sdate = true;
        if (d == 0) {
            k = 'hôm nay';
            sdate = false;
        } else if (d == 1) {
            k = 'hôm qua';
            sdate = false;
        } else k = f[j.getDay()];
        var result = (h % 12).toString() + ':' + m + ' ' + b + ' ' + k;
        if (sdate) result += ', ' + fill2(j.getDate()) + '/' + fill2(j.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + j.getFullYear();
        return result;
    }
    h = fill2(h);
    return h + ':' + m + ' ' + fill2(j.getDate()) + '/' + fill2(j.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + j.getFullYear();
}

function fill2(value) {
    return value < 10 ? ('0' + value) : value;
}
```

Thank So Much!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (input-output)? What value do you pass to `formatDateTime(a)` Do you have a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: input is int number : 1389334939
output:  08:53 19/02/2014

Comment: output in Safari (Iphone/Ipad) : NaN:NaN NaN/NaN/NaN;

Comment: And `1389334939` is what? Milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC?

Comment: TotalSeconds of DateTime.   //var j = new Date(a * 1000); is Milliseconds  since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC?

Comment: So it's seconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (ie unix time)

Comment: Yes. Is only error in safari on Iphone,Ipad

Comment: But `alert(new Date(1389334939 * 1000).toUTCString());` gives `Fri, 10 Jan 2014 06:22:19 GMT` and not `08:53 19/02/2014`

Comment: What do you expect the output to be if the function is given `1389334939` as the argument?

Comment: Input: 1389607501 Output : 17:05 13/01/2014

Comment: input: 1389334939 Output  13:22 10/01/2014

Comment: `alert(new Date(1389607501 * 1000).toUTCString());` gives `Mon, 13 Jan 2014 10:05:01 GMT`

Comment: `alert(new Date(1389334939 * 1000).toUTCString());` gives `Fri, 10 Jan 2014 06:22:19 GMT`

Comment: I'm GMT -7 And I need display in safari on Iphone/Ipad

Comment: And I was supposed to guess that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the MDN page regarding Javascript's [´Date´](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

Javascript

```
function pad(value) {
    return value < 10 ? ('0' + value) : value;
}

function formatDateTime(a) {
    var dateFromMillis = new Date(a * 1000),
        hours = pad(dateFromMillis.getUTCHours()),
        minutes = pad(dateFromMillis.getUTCMinutes()),
        date = pad(dateFromMillis.getUTCDate()),
        month = pad(dateFromMillis.getUTCMonth() + 1),
        year = dateFromMillis.getUTCFullYear();

    return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + date + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}

console.log(formatDateTime(1389334939))
```

Output

```
06:22 10/01/2014
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u5RVe/)

If you want it in your local time then remove `UTC` from the methods.